# Space between flash and text

Tags: php, html

In my site link

http://gpuzzles.com/games/tower-of-hanoi/

There is space difference between text and flash, how can i resolve it

Comment: do you want green background a bit lower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space belongs to the flash object, so the best solution is editting the flash file.

[image]

But you could also use `wmode=transparent` and a lower `z-index`to the flash, and use negative margins to fix the space.

Answer (score 2):

there are some work around to move the div have green background using `position:absolute` property and giving `z-index` a bit higher value.

So in your case you have to use `position:relative` in ID `#content-box-in-left-in` and then give the child div `position:absolute` and `top:` or `bottom` this way you can move the green background to anywhere by giving some value to `top` or `bottom`.

I can't make a Demo here as you only upload the website link not any Demo link.